# SVN subversion files not realized

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I had tortoise 'svn' installed on my PC and i had a working copy of my resources in the hard disk. But due to windows reinstallation i had to reinstall the svn client. After the re-installation my local 'svn' directory is not active and i am unable to do any updates or commits.

I have installed the 64 bit version now but I might have installed the 32 bit one previously.
So can this be due to 32 bit or 64 bit installer differences?  Any comments to resolve this issue please?

Any comments to resolve this issue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution at-last, Inside the the working copy root folder,Right click and select SVN upgrade working copy, It will upgrade the local sub version files to be compatible with the present svn installation.

Comment: I'll add that this is NOT a problem with 32-bit vs. 64-bit. Apparently before the Windows re-installation you were using an old version of SVN (probably 1.6 or 1.7) and then you installed the latest TortoiseSVN after your reinstall, which would give you SVN 1.8. The working copies for each of these versions are not compatible with each other, so you must upgrade the working copy format before you can use it with the new tool version.